# Making web3.js work from node server code

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript, nodejs

I'm running a geth node on the testnet and trying to run web3.js method from my node server code.

```
var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
console.log(coinbase);
```

However, I'm getting a provider not set or valid error. Who exactly is the provider here. Briefly, how do I bind my web3.js to my running geth client?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where did your `web3` object come from? It needs to be constructed with a `Provider` that tells it how to connect to an Ethereum node, like this:

`var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));`

Comment: How do i fifure out which ethereum node? Sorry, I'm new at this!

Comment: you can use the test net.  if you buy ether you can use production.  Or you can download geth and run it.  if you are impatient like me you can patch and build geth to quickly mine transactions for test purposes

Comment: I have a geth node running on testnet. What parameter do I pass as the Provider?

Comment: By default Geth will use port 8545, so for provider use: `http://localhost:8545`