# How can I use web3 on the server

Tags: web3js

I have a meteor app and would like to use web3 on the server. Wneh I call a web3 function I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: XMLHttpRequest is not a function
```

What do I have to do, that I can call web3 functions from the server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you using web3? Does this helps  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/making-web3-js-work-from-node-server-code ?

Comment: I'm running testrpc on the server and want to use web3. In Meteor.methods() I have a function which should write data to the contract which I deployed on testrpc. I did the following:

import { Web3 } from 'meteor/ethereum:web3'

if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
     web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
};

and when I call 

console.log(web3.eth.accounts);

I get then error message above

Comment: Bumblebee can you provide your code?